# How to get selected items valus from list box without using for loop

Tags: asp.net, listbox

I have a listbox as below in my aspx page

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="200"
></asp:ListBox>
```

I have bind this with category dataset. all working fine. now I want to get all the selected items from this list box at server side. there were many way to achieve those. but i dont want to iterate each item. becoz list item have 1000 of categories.

Any way to achieve this ?

Comment: any way you choose iterates through the collection to check the state of each and every item. How else can it know that it found all the selected items? Do you want a piece of code that fools you into believing that it doesn't iterate? Maybe something like this: `ddlCategory.Items.Where(item => item.Selected);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are sample example that will help you.

```
Dim lst As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox
lst.Items.Add(New ListItem("1", 1))
lst.Items.Add(New ListItem("2", 2))
lst.Items.Add(New ListItem("3", 3))
lst.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple
lst.Items(0).Selected = True
lst.Items(2).Selected = True
Dim selectedItems As List(Of ListItem) = (From li In lst.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)() Where li.Selected = True Select li).ToList
```

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this like this

```
var selectedItems = from li in ddlCategory.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                    where li.Selected == true
                    select li;
```

See another way of achieving it here

http://frazsundal.blogspot.com/2012/05/fetch-aspnet-listbox-control-selected.html

Comment: This is actually Linq, not lambda... Lambda looks like this for example: o => o.Id == 1

Comment: Changed my wording but that doesnot stop achieving its result :)

Comment: I know, just wanted to point it out so people won't learn it wrong :) The solution itself is good of course. +1

Answer (score 0):

you can get all the indexes of the selected items:

```
        int [] indexes= ListBox1.GetSelectedIndices();
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Length; i++)
        {
            // ListBox1.Items[i]  ;
        }
```